# How to write MySql select statement to get all defined settings or default settings not overridden for an id in one statement

Tags: php, mysql

In a table `myTable` defined as:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id |  name   |   value   |
|----+---------+-----------+
| 7  | hand    |  right    |
| 5  | hand    |  left     |
| 0  | hand    |  both     |
| 0  | feet    |  both     |
| 0  | eyes    |  green    |
| 9  | eyes    |  blue     |
| 2  | eyes    |  white    |
| 2  | hand    |  raised   |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Default settings are controlled by id = 0.

My question is how to write a select statement to get name,value for id = 5 in one query that will include set for id = 5 and any defaults not overridden.

The results should be:

```
+---------+-----------+
|  name   |   value   |
+---------+-----------+
| hand    |  left     |
| feet    |  both     |
| eyes    |  green    |
+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: so id=0 are the "defaults"?

Comment: This will be interesting, watching and learning...

Comment: Yes, id=0 are defaults for this example.  I'm pretty sure the single statement is possible using a select subquery and case and ultimately group by name....just need some help mixing it all in!

Comment: Can't tell if riddle/puzzle, 'clever' homework, or production code... >.<

Comment: Hi Cteski - Reduced to easy example for production code.  This is actually a small set of user_preferences on a gui.  Setting defaults in the same table for those simple preference affords one less table.  A different structure with two tables is another route, but different question (what is best way to set up to get/set user settings).  [sometimes I wish I were in school still!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clarified if the ordering of the result set is important, so might as well try:

```
SELECT name,
    value
FROM MyTable
WHERE id = 5
    AND id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE id = 0
        GROUP BY MyTable.id
    )
UNION
SELECT name,
    value
FROM MyTable
WHERE id = 0
    AND name NOT IN
    (
        SELECT name
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE id = 5
        GROUP BY MyTable.name
    )
```

Disclaimer: Tested in SQL Server, but not using anything specific to that version of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

seems this one may work for you:

```
SELECT id,name,value 
FROM test  
WHERE id = 5  
UNION 
SELECT id,name,value 
FROM test 
WHERE id=0 
and name not in (select name from test where id=5)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the try, but does not return the result expected, the default setting for hand  was returned instead of the overridden value.

Comment: hmm - i'm getting the needed

Comment: edited answer - checked with the data you've provided. It can select any combinations. Please check if you still need it.

Comment: Hi, does not return expected results, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/232ca6/2

Answer (score 1):

The following *does not return three rows* in the result set, it only returns a single row with columns `hand`, `feet` and `eyes`, so it may not work for you. But it should return the data that you're looking for given your conditions:

```
SELECT (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE name='hand' AND id=5)
        THEN (SELECT `value` FROM myTable WHERE name='hand' AND id=5)
        ELSE (SELECT `value` FROM myTable WHERE name='hand' AND id=0)
    END) AS hand,
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE name='feet' AND id=5)
        THEN (SELECT `value` FROM myTable WHERE name='feet' AND id=5)
        ELSE (SELECT `value` FROM myTable WHERE name='feet' AND id=0)
    END) AS feet,
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE name='eyes' AND id=5)
        THEN (SELECT `value` FROM myTable WHERE name='eyes' AND id=5)
        ELSE (SELECT `value` FROM myTable WHERE name='eyes' AND id=0)
    END) AS eyes
;
```

Output:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  hand   |   feet    |   eyes    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  left   |  both     |   green   |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

This is approach generates *10 different `SELECT`* statements rather than 1, and the accepted answer is, for most applications, probably a better way to go about it.

Comment: I'm just being very picky about giving the OP the same structure as he expects but otherwise this looks good.

Comment: Hi Patrick/Jeff, wanted to say why this wouldn't fit.  As project grows, the preferences (name/value) are growing, as we discover a place to allow user to set a preference we add a default setting.  That way when we get all settings, we don't need to know the individual names for a select.  In your attempt, for each new setting must also edit exponentially increasing statement.  Instead, look at the answer I accepted, we pump the result into an associative array and then let php do the rest as page is built/template filled in.

Comment: @Marc I appreciate that, thank you. I left this answer here solely for novelty. Someone may come by later and (for some reason unknowable) decide this way may work better for them, though the dynamic nature of the accepted answer confuses me as to why. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID = 5 
UNION
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID = 0 AND name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM MyTable
WHERE id = 5)
```

Should get you the right answer. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f516/14

Comment: Hi, does not create expected result and has an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f516/1

Comment: You are correct, Thank you. Really meant union as I didn't have a join clause. The edit now gives desired results.